An assassination of 6 targets at the same time where the last target is poisoned by book pages
My friend told me about an old movie he watched on TV, but couldn't remember the name. It's from the 1980-1990 era, I guess.
It's  about an assassin that attempts about 6 assassinations at the same time where the last person is sitting in his car and thinks he got away. He is reading the book the assassin wrote on the occasion about how he's killing everyone. When the target reaches the last page, he reads something like that "by the time you finished reading this book you were licking poison out of your thumb just enough for you to die on the last page".

Unless there was a remake, this is most likely The Internecine Project (1974) starring James Coburn.
He kills 4 former associates, but one of them has a notebook delivered to him with the poison on it.
